# Backbone.js: Always detect when a model has an attribute set, not /just/ changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

In Backbone, when I set the attribute of a Model to the same value it had before, "change" events do not trigger.

My View:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.$lastRollResult = this.$el.find('#lastRollResult');
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:lastRoll', this.render);
},

render: function() {
  this.$lastRollResult
    .html(this.model.get('lastRoll'))
    .addClass('shaking');

  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.$lastRollResult.removeClass('shaking');
  }, 1000);
},

events: {
  'click #button': function() {
    this.model.set('lastRoll', getRandomInteger(1, 6));
  }
}
```

Sometimes when I call getRandomInteger(), the int will be the same as the previous one, causing my .set('lastRoll', int) to not register as a "change" event. But this means my "shaking" class won't be applied, and that is bad.

How can I make Backbone *always* recognize when an attribute is set, even if the value I set was the same? Is there some sort of "set" event? (Didn't see one in the docs.)

**Edit:** I'm aware that there is probably a {silent: true} / .trigger() hack to accomplish this, but is there any "clean" or "semantic" way to always recognize a .set() call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force an update to a model's attribute to register as a change even if it isn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931233/can-i-force-an-update-to-a-models-attribute-to-register-as-a-change-even-if-it)

Comment: Found my answer in a duplicate topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931233/can-i-force-an-update-to-a-models-attribute-to-register-as-a-change-even-if-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your design is wrong. The view shouldn't be picking a random number and tell the model that that's its new value, the view should be telling the model to roll up a new number. Then you could have this in your model:

```
roll: function() {
    this.set('lastRoll', getRandomInteger(1, 6), { silent: true });
    this.trigger('change:lastRoll', this, this.get('lastRoll'));
}
```

and your view would simply `this.model.roll()`. Yes, you'd still be doing the `{silent:true}` and `trigger` hack but at least it would be in the right place.

Of course, this could have odd side effects so you could go behind the model's back and quietly unset the value before setting a new one:

```
roll: function() {
    // I suppose you could quietly unset here if you feel bad
    // about fiddling with `attributes`.
    this.attributes.lastRoll = null;
    this.set('lastRoll', getRandomInteger(1, 6));
}
```

Again, having a separate `roll` method on the model is a handy way to hide all this chicanery from the outside world.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I will make sure to honor MV*. Also thanks for the tip on the multiple arguments for trigger(), I wasn't aware it took more than 1. I like the attributes.attribute = null suggestion, it seems the quickest and I'll need to try it out (seems a little sketchy but it may work...).

Comment: You an always silently unset it if messing with `attributes` makes you nervous.